# I need data backup and all metadata backup of salesforce org including Managed package

Tags: apex, metadata, data-export, backup

I need data backup and all metadata backup of salesforce org including Managed package.
I need all components including managed package such as cloud sense .Please suggest

Comment: One option you can consider is to use clone sandbox option and create a cloned sandbox from the backup sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of vendors on the AppExchange that will happily sell you a solution to do this.

Full-scale data and metadata backup is not a built-in capability of Salesforce. If you'd like to do it yourself, you would be looking at combining the native [Weekly Data Export](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5) feature with a regular process to extract all of the metadata from your org using, most likely, an IDE or a Metadata API client like Salesforce DX or the [Force.com CLI](https://force-cli.heroku.com/).

Even using a purpose-built tool, backup and recovery is **never** a simple push-button operation, and backups lose a lot of their value if you do not have a detailed and rehearsed incident recovery plan in place.

Answer (score 0):

To backup all metadata from a Salesforce Org, you may also explore this: https://github.com/itlibrary/salesforce-metadata-backup

Make sure you list all the desired metadata types in build.properties. Many of them are already mentioned there for easy reference.